# XNA SpriteSortMode Speed and Shaders (4.0)

Tags: c#, xna, shader

Evening/afternoon;

I'm getting to grips with writing a little custom 2D XNA engine for my own personal use. When deciding on how to draw the 2D sprites, I'm stuck in a quandry:

Firstly, I'd like, at some point, to implement some *custom shader effects*. Every tutorial I read on the internet said that I therefore am forced to use **SpriteSortMode.Immediate**, except one, which said that in XNA 4.0 that is no longer necessary.

Furthermore, I am unsure about which SpriteSortMode is fastest for my approach, regardless of shading effects. *Ordering/layering of different sprites* is definitely a necessity (i.e. to have a HUD in front of the game sprites, and the game sprites in front of a backdrop etc.); but would it be faster to implement a custom sorted list and just call the Draw()s in order, or use the **BackToFront** / **FrontToBack** options?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Starting with XNA 4.0 you can use custom shader effects with any sprite sort mode. The Immediate sprite sort mode in XNA 3.1 was pretty broken. (see http://blogs.msdn.com/b/shawnhar/archive/2010/04/05/spritesortmode-immediate-in-xna-game-studio-4-0.aspx)

Concerning sorting I would say to sort them back to front for transparent sprites and front to back for opaque ones. See: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.xna.framework.graphics.spritesortmode.aspx
There is one extra interesting mode there (for a 2D engine at least), which is the Texture sorting mode where it sorts the draw calls by which texture is needed and thus reduces state change. That could be a big performance win for the main game sprites.

And I wouldn't worry too much about performance until your profiler says otherwise. SpriteBatch does quite a lot of batching (yes, really) and that will be the biggest performance improvement because it minimizes the number of state changes.

The only other way I can think of to improve performance is to use instancing, but I think that with XNA it might be a bad idea (ideally you'll want SM3.0 hardware and a custom vertex shader at least; I'm not sure how that plays with the SpriteBatch class).

Comment: Hi, in terms of the Texture sort mode... It says that it can improve performance in non-overlapping sprites of all similar depth... Two questions then:

Comment: One, will I still get that benefit if I split the draw routine into a few batches? And two, will that still retain the depth? Thank you

Comment: Yes, I was trying to find a use case for it (I don't typically do 2D engines) and was going to say you could set a depth for background sprites and one for foreground sprites. But foreground sprites might overlap so your system of splitting them in multiple batches could work better if there are not z-overlap.

Comment: Performance wise I think you're safe with a few dozen batches (but only the profiler could really tell). Where you will really get any benefit in that mode is when there are 1) different textures being used 2) lots of sprites using the same texture.